# How to send and receive data with ESP32 over BLE?

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, microcontroller, esp32

The ESP32 needs to communicate with a Crosss-Platform app through BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sending data over BLE

1. Define the function and the logic to send data byte-by-byte

```c
void sendSomeDataBLE(uint8_t *message, int messageSize) {
        uint8_t txValue = 0;

        while (txValue < messageSize) {
          pTxCharacteristic->setValue(&message[txValue], 1);
          pTxCharacteristic->notify();
          txValue++;
          delay(100); // bluetooth stack will go into congestion, if too many packets are sent
        }
}
```

2. Calculate the message length, malloc a character array

```c
int messageLength = 10; // or measure someway
uint8_t* message = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*messageLength);
```

3. Pass the pointer of the uint8_t array to the function

```c
sendSomeDataBLE(&message[0], messageLength);
```

### Receiving data over BLE

1. Define the function to compare the received value with a string

```c
bool compareData(std::string received, std::string predefined) {
  int receivedLength = received.length();
  int predefinedLength = predefined.length();

  if ((receivedLength / 2) != predefinedLength) {
    return false;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < predefinedLength; i++) {
    if (received[i * 2] != predefined[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

2. Capture all the data received through the callback function

```c
class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string rxValue = pCharacteristic->getValue();
      std::string lwnCommand = "lwn";
      if (compareData(rxValue, lwnCommand)) {
        Serial.println("lwn command received");
      }
   }
}
```

Also, you do need to initiate the BLE and set up the characterestics for RX and TX.

Comment: Heyy i am having difficulty in forming the whole structure of the code, can you please share the complete code ?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you're talking about ionic. In which case, you can use a BLE plugin, use protobufs to implement the transport layer, then add in curce25519 cryptography & SHA256 hashing for the proof of possession (if you're using it) to create a shared key. Then use AES (CTR mode) encryption / decryption. Lastly you'll need to create your protobuf _pb.js files to shove into something like google-protobuf.js to actually generate your messages.

It's not simple.

### BLE Plugin

First thing to so is get it up and running:

```
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble/ngx';
```

is a good one. There are good tutorials out there to get this working.

### Protobuffers

I'd recommend google-protobuf. Use commonJS imports to bring in your .proto files as _pb.js:

```
$ protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. messages.proto base.proto
```

Then in the your .ts file, use something like:

```
var messages = require("../../assets/js/wifi_scan_pb");
var message = new messages.RespScanStatus();
```

as an example for how to use the Scan Results end point.

### Cryptography

It says it's optional, but realistically, if you aren't using it, you are an idiot. So, don't skip this step because it's hard. You can use something like:

```
import { sharedKey, generateKeyPair } from 'curve25519-js';

let keyPairClient = generateKeyPair(seedClient);
let keyPairDevice = generateKeyPair(seedDevice);
let shared_key = sharedKey(keyPairClient.private, keyPairDevice.public);

...  you get the picture...
```

and then maybe use crypto-js to piece together the rest of teh encryption. it comes rolled up with AES, SHA256. Don't forget to incorportate the Proof of Possession in the shared keyt generation. It offers a worthwhile level of security.

### Then What

Send and receive stuff from the device. It's all standard BLE stuff. And I don't say that whimsically because I know everything about BLE, I can say it because the library I recommended handles it fine, despite the fact that I know nothing about BLE.

Sorry it's a massive pain in the backside, but that's the honest answer of what you'll need to do to send stuff with ESP32 using BLE.